# Pyspark using map function to apply to list of columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following list which contains some column names from a dataframe `df`

```
stringList = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

I want to count the distinct values in these columns. I saw the code below but it does not seems to work.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

distinctList = []
def countDistinctCats(colName):
  count = df.agg(countDistinct(colName)).collect()
  distinctList.append(count)

# Apply function on every column
map(countDistinctCats, stringList)
print(distinctList)
```

However, the following two approaches seem to work well:

```
result = map(lambda x: df.agg(countDistinct(col(x))).collect(), stringList) 
print(list(result))
```

This approach is very slow, compared to the one below:

```
display(df.agg(*(countDistinct(col(c)).alias(c) for c in stringList)))
```

Why the first code block does not work?

Comment: First one aggregate multiple times but the second is just once.

Comment: Thanks. But why the approach with function `countDistinctCats` does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question: Why does not the first block run?

According to doc https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.countDistinct, **countDistinct** expects `column` not a `string`.

Your code block `df.agg(countDistinct(colName))` passes a string to it, since it is python, such things are not caught at compile-time and you will get an exception at runtime.

Comment: In the link you posted, there is an example where the function takes String to get count distinct.

Comment: Yea, @chintans, my bad. What version of python are you using? If it is python3 then this code `map(countDistinctCats, stringList)` will not invoke the function as it will produce a generator which are lazy in nature.